# Meteor: Add class to one MongoDB element retrieved

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have an `<ul>` which renders each element retrieved with `<li>` but I want to set one random result as `<li class="active">` so when an user enters the site, it will render at least one element, then user must interact with website to render next or previous elements...

No it renders everything with `<li>` as I said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add the class "active" to a random list-item (and only one), the easiest solution for me is to use jQuery with something like that.

```
Meteor.Template.rendered = function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  var $li = $("#MyList li");
  $li.eq(random % $li.length).addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked! But it would be perfect if meteor html tags have this kind of options which are essential for almost all projects :(